# Is this a safe way to convert MySQL tables from latin1 to utf-8?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I need to change all the tables in one of my databases from latin1 to utf-8 (with utf8_bin collation).

I have dumped the database, created a test database from it, and run the following without any errors or warnings for each table:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARSET utf8 COLLATION utf8_bin
```

Is it safe for me to repeat this on the real database? The data seems fine by inspection...

Comment: Somehow I think there is a lot more to the conversion... in the past, we always had to dump and re-up the data.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm afraid of! I've seen about 100 PHP scripts for dumping tables, regexing out the latin1, then re-inserting it. I'm keen to avoid that if possible, and I'm almost certain that all the data is currently sane characters (think ASCII character-set) but don't really understand how MySQL stores and converts this.

Comment: Why don't you put some edge case examples into a sample db and try the convert...

Comment: I think you can do it in place if you turn everything into blobs, do the conversion and then turn it back - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-conversion.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 3 different cases to consider:

### The values are indeed encoded using Latin1

This is the consistent case: declared charset and content encoding match. This was the only case I covered in my initial answer.

Use the command you suggested:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Note that the `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` command only appeared in MySQL 4.1.2, so anyone using a database installed before 2005 had to use an export/import trick. This is why there are so many legacy scripts and document on Internet doing it the old way.

### The values are already encoded using utf8

In this case, you don't want mysql to convert any data, you only need to change the column's metadata.

For this, you have to change the type to BLOB first, then to TEXT utf8 for each column, so that there are no value conversions:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 BLOB;
ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

This is the recommended way, and it is explicitely documented in [Alter Table Syntax Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

### The values use in a different encoding

The default encoding was Latin1 for several years on a some Linux distributions. In this case, you have to use a combination of the two techniques:

- Fix the table meta-data, using the BLOB type trick
- Convert the values using `CONVERT TO`.

Comment: Itching to -1. A straightforward conversion will break any existing accents.

Comment: @Denis: You are right, I assumed the table content was consistent (like a Latin1 charset with latin1 content), although nfm did not specify it. @nfm: what is the charset effectively used by the content?

Comment: I'm in over my head with this stuff but user data is coming from an english language website with `<meta charset="utf8">`. I'm almost certain that all data is currently using the english alphabet and common ASCII symbols (@, $ etc). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, in this case, you don't want data to be converted. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I believe the first case did apply to me - looking at the MySQL settings the client and server were both using latin1. In any case, I ran `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` on each table without issue and all of the data seems fine. Thanks!

Comment: COLLATION should be COLLATE (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward conversion will potentially break any strings with non-utf7 characters.

If you don't have any of those (i.e. all of your text is english), you'll usually be fine.

If you've any of those, however, you need to convert all char/varchar/text fields to blob in an initial run, and to convert them to utf8 in a subsequent run.

See this article for detailed procedures:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets

Comment: Note that the linked article is a bit outdated: it doesn't use a single `CONVERT TO` which has existed for 6 years and makes things much easier. That being said, it's a good reference, and if works for both older and newer databases.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this a few times on production databases in the past (converting from the old standard encoding swedish to latin1), and when MySQL encounters a character that cannot be translated to the target encoding, it aborts the conversion and remains in the unchanged state. Therefor, I'd deem the ALTER TABLE statement working.